# Javascript runs in a loop for setting website language via geolocation

Tags: javascript

I got this code from support.wix.com/en/article/corvid-tutorial-redirecting-visitors-based-on-browser-language

But when I use this code in Corvid of WIX in redirects my page every second. So my website is reloading in a loop.

I hope you can help me finding the issue.

Thanks and best regards
Nader

```
import wixLocation from 'wix-location';
import wixWindow from 'wix-window';

$w.onReady(function () {

 setTimeout(function () {

  switch (wixWindow.browserLocale) {

  case "ru-RU":
  case "ru":
   wixLocation.to('https://www.plastmass-group.net/?lang=ru');
   break;

  default:
   wixLocation.to('https://www.plastmass-group.net/?lang=en');
   break;
  }

 }, 1);

});
```

Comment: I think you should remove the `setTimeout()` wrapping, let it be just `onReady()` -> `switch()`

Comment: I think you need to redirect to a page that does not contain any of the above javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your hints! I will try these options and let you know if they worked.

Comment: @ksav Yes, you have been right. Redirecting to another page helped. But then I need to create a fake start page with the code for my website to redirect to the real start page with the correct language.

Is there no way to limit a code?

Comment: What do you want to limit?

Comment: That the code only loads one time, when you visit the website. Limit the code for one visit.